# stop input clearing onFocus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this auto-suggestion application for emails. it all works well, except when I click outside the input field and then click back in it clears what was there 'onFocus'. any Ideas how I can stop this from happening?

```
function suggest(inputString){
    if(inputString.length == 0) {
      $('#suggestions').fadeOut();
    } else {
    $('#email').addClass('load');
        $.post("auto.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){
            if(data.length >0) {
                $('#suggestions').fadeIn();
                $('#suggestionsList').html(data);
                $('#email').removeClass('load');
          }
      });
   }
}

 function fill(thisValue) {
    $('#email').val(thisValue);
    setTimeout("$('#suggestions').fadeOut();", 600);
}

<input type="text" id="email" onKeyUp="suggest(this.value);" onClick="fill();" />
```

Comment: `fill()` is passing a null value every time you click it.  Get rid of `$('#email').val()` and it won't.

Comment: @Archer technically its passing `undefined`, which isn't the same thing as `null`.

Comment: @Aren, technically yes.  Different word, but same result though :)

Comment: On an unrelated note, is there a specific reason you're using `onClick` and `onKeyUp` attributes? jQuery enables you to seperate form from function by not making the DOM reliant on the javascript implementation. You should be using `$().on(...)` or at least `$().click(...)` etc....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onClick="fill();"` call on your element is executing `fill(undefined)` whenever you click on the input box.

The first thing this does is sets the value of the input box to `thisValue` (currently holding `undefined`) which would effectively erase your input box.

This has nothing to do with focus, try clicking the box, entering a value then clicking on the box again, it'll likely wipe the value too without clicking off first.

---

For what it's worth, you're probably over-complicating this. I imagine the requirement for the clearing of the box is to remove placeholder text. If you're designing for a remotely new browser use the HTML5 `placeholder="E-Mail"` to have the browser display that in a lighter text (or whatever) when the user hasn't entered anything.

If you have to support older browsers there's ways around this too, this is a simple but not perfect way (you can generalize this and make a jQuery plugin or go find one out there that exists already too):

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="email" class="placeholder" value="E-Mail" />
```

CSS:

```
.placeholder { color: #ccc; }
```

Javascript:

```
;(function($) {

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#email").on('focus', function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      if ($this.hasClass('placeholder')) {
        $this.removeClass('placeholder');
        $this.val('');
      }
    });

    $("#email").on('keyUp', function() {
      // this is where your key-up code goes
    });

  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: oh yeah, it does. any way around this?

Comment: @user2014429 Sure, but you need some criteria to define when you want a focus to clear the box and when you don't.